# Put if conditions in route laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am very new in laravel.I have following to routes and I need to check the condition if the user already exists in db then call different controller, besides I want both of these actions on a single HTML form with single to submit button that already generates the form to save new user using laravel blade engine. What action do I need to specify on the form?
P.S the form has only one button.

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'save'], function(){
Route::get('/customer', [
    'uses' => 'CustomerController@SaveCustomer',
    'as' => 'save.customer'
    ]);

Route::get('/order',[
    'uses'=> 'OrderController@PlaceOrder',
    'as' => 'save.order'

]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should  use  Middleware

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware

On middleware you should check user/user rights and make redirection based on user rights